# How to set multi-line text for kivyMD's MDRaisedButton?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am struggled to use the MDRaisedButton component from KivyMD.

```
MDRaisedButton:
     text: 'a\nb'
     size_hint: 0.15,0.15
     pos_hint: {"right":1, "y":0}
```

As shown from "\n", it is intended to have two-line content in this button. But what happens is just the 2nd line is shown. `multiline: True` does not work for kivyMD's `MDRaisedButton`... just with kivy's `Button`... I would like to use the `MDRaisedButton` because of the easiness for the color theme related issues...

There is any way to set multi-line for `MDRaisedButton`?

Comment: I believe that your `size_hint: 0.15,0.15` is too small to fit both lines. Try increasing the `height`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you very much...